# Python pull column list from txt then remove duplicates and sort in newlist

Tags: python, sorting, duplicates, coding-efficiency

Hello StackOverflow Community,  Learning Python it took a week for me to read/learn how to put together 4 individual scripts to do what i needed.  Step1.....Step4.  Each ran perfect but separately.  Now I'm trying to combine steps and hopefully/eventually into one step. Step1.py is to read a txt file (1000+ rows) column 5 (separated using \t) and remove last 2 characters from string (not needed). This is then placed in a output1.txt file. Step2.py script opens the output1.txt file, reads mixchar words(one mixchar word per line), removes duplicates and sorts remaining mixchar words (these mixchar words must stay in original order within the word) and output2.txt is created and populated. Step3 & Step4 cross reference output2.txt with two other txt file lists for matches.  My question is this: through trial & error with learning how pycharm debug works I have a variable that grabs correctly the column mixchar word and I can output.write() to txt. But when I try to add a remove duplicate code within the same script the variable grabs a single character within the string and proceses it instead of the complete string(mixchar word). The below Step1.py script works and prints to output1.txt. If I REM the output lines and add the newlist section, this is where I start having troubles.  I can assign (line.split()[4][:-2]) to a variable as (rc). Then see the string mixchar word 1st 6 chars. which is good. Then trying to check if variable is in newlist = [] it is checking for the 1st character only. It separates the mixchar word by commas hence why I have the print(''.join(newlist)) at bottom of Step1. I feel Python can do this and mouthwatering close to figuring this out but would like to buy a clue to get me over this hurdle. Then I can start concentrating on Step3&4 and seeing if word exist in the other two lists.  Hope this make sense. Forgive my long windiness. Appreciate any help.

cf.txt example piece. Dots (periods) are one per column (A-D). Mixchar words start in column E
ABCDE
header row
. . . . 5JESYMC2
. . . . 2TEHUOB1
. . . . TWSIHNB2
. . . . SYHNRWE2
. . . . BFHYSJF1

```
'''
Step1.py
cf = open(r"E:\Testing\test2\cf.txt","r")
output = open(r"E:\Testing\test2\output1.txt","w")

next(cf)
for line in cf:
    output.write(line.split()[4][:-2])
    output.write("\n")

#rc = (line.split()[4][:-2])
#newlist = []
#for item in rc:
#    if item not in newlist:
#        newlist.append(item)
#    else
#        newlist.sort()
#        print(''.join(newlist))

cf.close()
output.close()


Step2.py
output1 = open(r"E:\Testing\test2\output1.txt", "r").readlines()
content_set = set(output1)
output2 = open(r"E:\Testing\test2\output2.txt", "a+")

for line in content_set:
    output2.write(line)
    output2.close()

fname = ("E:/Testing/test2/output2.txt")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
newlist=[]
for line in fh:
    lst+=line.split()
    for item in lst:
        if item not in newlist:
            newlist.append(item)
            newlist.sort()
import sys
sys.stdout = open("E:/Testing/test2/output2.txt", 'w')
print('\n'.join(newlist))

sys.stdout.close()
```

'''

Finished hopeful outcome. Sorted by 1st character only. Top to bottom new line per mixchar word

2TEHUO
5JESYM
BFHYSJ
SYHNRW
TWSIHN

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way but it is providing the results I would like to see. If anyone can improve this please let me know. I would appreciate it.

```
cf = open(r"E:\Testing\test2\cf.txt", "r+")
output = open(r"E:\Testing\test2\output1.txt", "w+")

next(cf)
newlist = []
for line in cf:
rc = (line.split()[4][:-2]) #grabs 5th col string and removes last 2 chars.
if rc not in newlist:       #ask if string exist in newlist.
    newlist = []            #clears newlist. 
    newlist.append(rc)      #appends rc string to newlist if new.
    if rc:                  #ask if rc string empty.
        output.write(str(newlist)[2:-2])    #writes to output file and removes 
                                            #leading/ending 2 chars. which are ['  ']
        output.write('\n')  #adds new line to output to create vertical list.
```